# Yii 1.1.6: Display one-to-many related model in CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I have a one to many relations of a team and it's players in a database table and I can successfully view the team info from the `team/view` page.

How can I add the players for that team under the team, something like below:

```
Team A
Team A description

Team A players
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Player Name | Position | Shirt Number | Rating | Date Created |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Mike        | Striker  | 10           | 8      | Jan 13 2016  |
| Ken         | Keeper   | 1            | 9      | Oct 10 2015  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### EDIT

This is my relation in model `Team.php`

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'players' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TeamPlayers', 'teamID'),
        'created' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'createdBy'),
    );
}
```

This is my controller `controllers/TeamController.php`

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = Team::model()->findByPk((int)$id);
    if($model === null) {
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    }

    $this->render('view',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

This is the `views/team/view.php` file:

```
<h1><?php echo 'Team '.$model->teamName; ?></h1>
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
            'teamID',
            'teamName',
            'teamDescription',
            'created.userName',
            'dateCreated',
        ),
    ));
?>

<h2>Team players</h2>

<?php
    $players = $model->players;
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'team-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$players,
            'columns'=>array(
                'playerName',
                'position',
                'shirtNumber',
                'rating',
                'dateCreated'
            ),
    ));
?>
```

This results in this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /yii-1.1.6/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php on line 105
```

Which is because of this line in my view.php file:

```
'dataProvider'=>$players,
```

---

And so my question is, how can I get the `teamPlayers` dataProvider for use in the gridview in my `team/view.php` file?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post your code.

Comment: How do you create dataProvider? Show your controller's action.

Comment: @aslawin Added under the model code

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how do you create `dataProvider`. Using relation `$model->players` data is not prepared for using it in `CGridView`.

You should create method in `Team` model that prepares dataProvider with players. This should looks like this:

```
public function getPlayersDataProvider()
{
    $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamPlayers WHERE teamID = :teamId')->queryScalar(array(':teamId'=>$this->id));

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TeamPlayers WHERE teamID = :teamId';
    $rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, array(':teamId'=>$this->id));

    $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
        'id'=>'id',
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20,
        ),
    ));

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This method creates `CArrayDataProvider` instance. I use in this method raw SQL, because its easier to create `CArrayDataProvider` with array data. Now in your `CGridView` widget change `dataProvider` to something like this:

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->getPlayersDataProvider(),
```

Comment: @Parto, I've added return statement to my function.

Comment: Cool. Let me try it out